# Understanding the BPP inside DICOM images

Tags: dicom

I'm working with DICOM files since a few days, using FO-DICOM.

I'm using a set of dicom files for my tests, and I've been printing the "Photometric Interpretation" and the "Sample Per Pixel" values, to have a better understanding of what kind of images I'm working with.

The result was "MONOCHROME2" for the Photometric Interpretation, and "1" for the Sample Per Pixel.

What I understood by reading the part3 of the standard is that MONOCHROME2 represent a gray scale, starting from black for its minimum values.

But what is the Sample Per Pixel exactly? I thought this was representing the number of **bytes** (and not bits) per pixel (that would be logic to have 8 **bits** per pixel for a scale of gray right?)

But my problem here is that actually, my images seem to have 32 bpp.
I'm working with 512*512 pixels images, and I converted them into byte arrays. So I was expecting arrays of 512*512=262144 bytes.
But I get arrays of 1048630 bytes (which is a bit more than 4*262144)

Does someone have an explanation?

**EDIT:**

Here's are some of my datas :

```
PhotometricInterpretation=MONOCHROME2
SamplePerPixel=1
BitsAllocated=16
BitsStored=12
HighBit=11
PixelRepresentation=0
NumberOfFrames=0
```

Comment: About the sample data: Unsigned 12-bit data encoded with 16-bit alignment, The lower 12-byte are the pixel values. 0 is black, 4096 is white. If it is a CT, I'd expect it to have a RescaleSlope attribute near -1000 which maps the pixel values to hounsfield units. When Rows = Cols = 512, the pixeldata must be 0,5 MB (512 * 512 * 2 bytes) otherwise the dataset is not correctly encoded.  NumberOfFrames = 0 is an encoding error for sure.

Comment: ...assumed that the dataset is uncompressed

Comment: Thank you, I'll manipulate these datas to train myself and maybe come back later if there's still something not clear :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The attribute (0028,0002) `SamplesPerPixel` refers to color images only and tells you the number of planes which are present in the image (e.g. 3 for RGB), so you have

```
PhotometricInterpretation=RGB
SamplesPerPixel=3
```

With 8 bits per pixel (I will revisit BPP below). As long as you have `PhotometricInterpretation` = MONOCHROME1 or MONOCHROME2, you can expect the `SamplesPerPixel` to be 1 and nothing else.

What you do have to take into consideration is the number of bits per pixel:

```
BitsAllocated (0028,0100)
BitsStored (0028,0101)
HighBit (0028,0102)
```

These tell you how many bits are used to encode a pixel value (`BitsAllocated`) and which of these bits really contain grayscale information (`BitsStored`, `HighBit`). `HighBit` is zero-based and usually but not necessarily = `BitsStored-1`

An example to illustrate this: For CT images, it is very common to express gray values in hounsfield units which range from -1000 to +3000. These are represented by 12 bits which are stored with a 2-byte-alignment, so

```
BitsAllocated (0028,0100) = 16
BitsStored (0028,0101) = 12
HighBit (0028,0102) = 11
```

Another degree of freedom is `PixelRepresentation` which tells you if the pixel data is encoded unsigned (0) or in 2s complement (1). I have seen both for CT images, however signed pixel data is rather unusual for image types other than CT.

In your example, I would assume that Bits Allocated == 32 or (not very likely) that you have a dataset containing multiple images ('frames'), so `NumberOfFrames (0028,0008)` > 1. If Number of Frames is absent, you can safely assume to have only one frame.

I have over-simplified a bit here, especially about color images but I think this is complicated enough ;-). Basically, DICOM offers any thinkable degree of freedom to encode pixel data and describe the encoding in the header.

I think I have recommended you to have a look at the DCMTK in a recent post. The DicomImage class features a nice interface (`getInterData()`) which cares about all that stuff and provides the pixel data read from a DICOM file in a normalized format.

**[EDIT]:** Feel free to post a DICOM dump of your dataset here, I would have a look at it and tell you how to interpret the pixel data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm still trying to use fo-dicom, I'll look at DCMTK later maybe, for the moment I'm trying to understand how it works! I edited my post

Comment: Don't want to talk you into using DCMTK, but I do not know FO-DICOM

Comment: If Sample Per Pixel ( 0028:0002) has a value greater than 1 (3 for RGB image), Planar Configuration (0028:0006) having a value of 0 means color-by-pixel (RBG, RGB, RGB) and 1 means color-by-plane (red plane, green plane and red plane).